# Find all paths between two graph nodes below given length/weight of path

Tags: python, path, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I'm trying to find an efficient method to obtain all possible paths between two nodes under the condition that the path does not include more than a given maximum of nodes. For simplicity, let's assume the graph in the below picture:

[image]

So let's say I'm interested in going from 1->5. With different maximum lengths of paths (i call it path_length_limit), the results would be something like:

findPaths(1,5,path_length_limit=3) --> [[1,2,5],[1,4,5]]

findPaths(1,5,path_length_limit=4) --> [[1,2,5],[1,4,5],[1,2,3,5]]

findPaths(1,5,path_length_limit=5) --> [[1,2,5],[1,4,5],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,4,5]

I have not found any examples of how to do this efficiently. In the real case, I have many thousands of nodes, so finding all possible paths from source to target first and then store those of length shorter than X is not an alternative, it becomes very time consuming.

Any tips or examples?

Comment: Do you agree, if the solution will be created in C++?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov - I'm only familiar with Python. But it might be translatable from C++ to Python?

Comment: Modifying the Floyd-Warshal algorithm should get you this.